# Putting two MySQL rows into an PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, mysqli

I am developing a narrowcasting system for my school and I am currently using a JavaScript to rotate between URL's for the iFrame on the main display page.

I want to be able to change these values through a backend with PHP. However I can't figure out how to put 2 rows (module_url and module_time) into a array and echo it to JS.

Browsing through stackoverflow I tried a variety of code and this one kinda works, except it will throw out URL's like: "`var arrayObjects = ["https:\/\/domain.eu\/dir\/page.php","https:\/\/domain.eu\/dir\/page.php"]`".

(I want the array to display: "`var arrayObjects = ["https:\/\/domain.eu\/dir\/page.php", 20]`". Where the URL stands for the new iFrame source and the 20 for the time the page will be displayed.)

So my main question is, how do I make 2 rows fit into 1 array and how do I make sure the array will display correct links aswell as the module time.

```
    <?php
   $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pw', 'db');
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT module_url FROM db")) {
        $stmt->bind_result($name);
        $OK = $stmt->execute();
    }
    //put all of the resulting names into a PHP array
    $result_array = Array();
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $result_array[] = $name;
    }
    //convert the PHP array into JSON format, so it works with javascript
    $json_array = json_encode($result_array);
?>

<script>
    //now put it into the javascript
    var arrayObjects = <?php echo $json_array; ?>
ALL OTHER JS CODE
</script>
```

Edit: module_time is not added to the MySQLi query at the moment.

Comment: $result = $OK->get_result();
$array = $result->fetch_assoc();
Try this maybe this helps

Comment: @Tassilo, please let me know if I understood your questions correctly. So you want to add 2 records in an array like [url1, time], [url2, time]?

Comment: You can use this: `var arrayObjects = JSON.parse('<?php echo $json_array; ?>')`

Comment: @imprezzeb That's correct! The JS array currently looks like this: 'https://domain.eu/dir/page.php', 45,
  'https://domain.eu/dir/page.html', 25,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your PHP array should be multi-deminsional like:

```
$result_array[] = array($name, <time here>);
```

Then since you already use json_encode and assigned it to JS array, it is indeed already an array in Javascript, that is you can already access the elements like:

```
arrayObjects[0][0]; <---- first element URL
arrayObjects[0][1]; <---- first element time
```

Printing JavaScript array to HTML will show it as text like:

```
http://www.google.com,20,http://www.google.com,30
```

By the way you can use JSON.stringify() to print the actual Javascript array instead of the text, sample:

```
var array = JSON.stringify(<?php echo $json_array; ?>);
document.write(array);
```

Will output:

```
[["http://www.google.com",20],["http://www.google.com",30]]
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a bunch! It now prints this: var arrayObjects = [["https:\/\/domain.eu\/dir\/page.php","5"], Do you know how to remove the quotation marks around the seconds and how to sanitize the URL?

Comment: Welcome, I'm glad to help. Happy coding.

Comment: I got the URL's working, except array output still looks like this:  `var frames = JSON.stringify([["https://domain.eu/dir/page.php","5"],` While it needs to be in this format: `'https://domain.eu/dir/page.php', 45,`. So without the [[ ]] and only single quotes on the url and no quotes on seconds. Can that be done? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Tassilo, if you need the actual data type for each element in array you don't need to call JSON.stringify() on it as it covnerts the array to strings. You use this for display purposes only. To replace all double quotes with single after calling JSON.stringify(), you can use array.replace(/"/g, "'");